# Prevent browser window from scaling when chrome dev tools pane is open

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome's dev tools starting behaving strangely today. When I expand the dev tools pane, the main browser window scales down proportionately rather than becoming narrower (or shorter).

I've searched through the settings to see if there is something I inadvertently checked or unchecked, but haven't had any luck. I've also disabled all extensions and verified that I'm on the current version of Chrome.

You can see the effect in the screenshots below. The browser pane in the first screen shot has already scaled down, and scales further as I expand the dev tools pane in the second shot.

What should I do to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out it was a combination of settings I had inadvertently checked.

1. In Developer Tools Settings, **Show 'Emulation' view in console drawer** has to be checked
2. In the console drawer, on the Emulation tab, if **Emulate screen** and **Shrink to fit** are both checked, the browser window will scale as the dev tools pane is resized.

I unchecked **Emulate screen** and all is well.

Comment: I noticed the same thing on mine, couldn't figure it out.  Thanks.